# Add copy constructor to a class

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, copy-constructor

Is it possible to add a copy constructor (or in other words to overload it) for class which I did not write?

For example, I am using some library that have a Point class. I want to add a copy constructor to it. I can not and do not want to edit it.

Imaginary syntax:

```
cv::Point cv::Point::Point(const AnotherPoint& p){
    return cv::Point(p.x,p.y);
}
```

P.S I did not write `AnotherPoint` also.

**EDIT -Problem Background-:**

All my problem that I want to copy `std::vector<cv::Point>` to another `std::vector<AnotherPoint>` using the standard  function `std::copy`. So I was seraching for a way to overload the copy constructor to make it.

Comment: You could probably use `std::transform` to carry out your copy.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. many thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

You can do the opposite, though, i.e. define an implicit [*conversion operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) from your type (`AnotherPoint`) to the the other one (`cv::Point`).

This way, you will be able to use an object of type `AnotherPoint` everywhere a `cv::Point` is expected.

If you don't have control over `AnotherPoint` too, I guess the only way to go is to define a *standalone function* that create a `cv::Point` from a `AnotherPoint`.

**After OP EDIT:**

Eventually, to transform a `vector<cv::Point>` into a `vector<AnotherPoint>` you can use the standalone function mentioned above as the `unary_op` of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), as @TartanLlama suggested.

Comment: Thank you. This is totally helpful. Bu I have forget to mention that Another point is not under my control so.

Comment: Will it work during copy? I mean will it be a copy constructor ? without using std::transform

Comment: @HumamHelfawi no, you'd need to call it directly, like `anotherToCv(myAnotherPoint);`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add constructors to a type after its definition.

A simple way to copy a `std::vector<cv::Point>` to a `std::vector<AnotherPoint>` would be to use `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> cvPoints;
//cvPoints filled
std::vector<AnotherPoint> otherPoints;
otherPoints.reserve(cvPoints.size()); //avoid unnecessary allocations
std::transform(std::begin(cvPoints), std::end(cvPoints),
               std::back_inserter(otherPoints), 
               [](const cv::Point& p){ return AnotherPoint{p.x, p.y}; });
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I answered a pretty different question though (before OP's edits), so I'll leave my answer.